# Tab panel with non-panel views

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a situation and it's a little complicated, so please bear with me.

I am writhing an application for iPhone with Phonegap and Sencha Touch 2. The landing page has various options in a list that allows the user to direct to other views(This is done by adding the view to Ext.Viewport and changing the active item).

There are three views that I want to make available all through the app using the Sencha Tab panel.

Here's my question:
How do I direct the app to views that are not tabs on the tab panel while still keeping the tab panel available to the user on those views?

Hope this makes sense... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a default toolbar with buttons how access your defaults views.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the following setup:

- mainview

  - tab view container

    - view tab 1
    - view tab 2
    - view tab 3
  - another-view

you could switch to 'another-view' like this:

```
var otherView = Ext.getCmp('another-view');
var mainView = Ext.getCmp('mainview');
mainView.setActiveItem(otherView);
```